# Build a data frame that each rows has incremental numbers in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to build a data frame with **m** column and **n** rows.
Each rows start with **1** and increment by **1** until **m**.

I've tried to find a solution, but I found only this solution for the columns.
I have also added a figure of a simple case.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how it's not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np
m = 4
n = 3
out = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(np.arange(1,m), (n,1)), columns=[f'c{num}' for num in range(m-1)])
```

Output:

```
   c0  c1  c2
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
```

Comment: Thank you. You are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `assign` to broadcast the rows in an empty DataFrame:

```
df = (
 pd.DataFrame(index=range(3))
   .assign(**{f'c{i}': i+1 for i in range(4)})
    )
```

Output:

```
   c0  c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (no additional libraries needed):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'c{n}': [n + 1] * (m - 1) for n in range(m)})
```

Result with m = 4:

```
   c0  c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

We just do `np.one`

```
m = 3
n = 4
out = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((m,n))*(np.arange(n)+1))
Out[139]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```